# Start RunAs from Powershell variable

Tags: powershell

I have this command that works fine in the commandline:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:MyPC\User "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

Now I want to add this to a PowerShell script.
However, this code doesn't give an error, but doesn't do anything at all.

```
$cmd = 'C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:MyPC\User "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"'
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

What am I doing wrong? 
(I'm using PowerShell 4.0)

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: What's wrong with just using the exact same command in PowerShell? There's no need for `Invoke-Expression` here, PowerShell can invoke `runas` with arguments just as well as `cmd` can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Start-Process` cmdlet to run external executables:

```bsh
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe -ArgumentList "/user:MyPC\User `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe`""
```